# Need combinatorial formula

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, trees

Let we have a forest $F_n(P)$ with $n$ nodes   defined by set $P$ of all pairs $\{\text{father}, \text{son}\}$. For instance $P=\{\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4 \}, \{1, 3 \}\}$  defines a forest $F_5(P).$

Let $k_i$ is the number  of descendants  the node $i$.  For the forest $F_5$ we have $k_1=3, k_2=0, k_3=1,k_4=0.$

Let $K_n(P)$ be the number of all triplets  $\{i,j,k\}$ such that no one of the pairs  $\{i,j\}$,  $\{i,k\}$,  $\{j,k\}$  belong to $F_n.$ 
For example,   for the  forest(tree) $F_5(P)$  defined  abowe there are  3  such triplets:
$$
\left\{ \{1,4,5\},\{2,3,5\},\{2,4,5\} \right\}. 
$$

**Question**  Is it possyble to express $K_n(P)$ in terms of $k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n?$ If  no,  then what a  set of parameters  of $P$  we should to   calculate to find  $K_n(P)$?

For  any $P$ I can  find $K_n(P)$ by brute  forse algorithm but I am interesting in exact combinatorial formula. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  Your $k_i$ parameters are not enough to reconstruct the graph, and not enough to count triangles in the complementary graph (which is what $K_n$ represents).

For example, consider $P=\{\{1,2\},\{2,5\}\}$ and $Q=\{\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,5\}\}$.  They have the same $k_i$ parameters, namely $2,1,0,0,0$.  However the first one has five triangles in the complementary graph (so $K_4=5$), while the second has only two.

Comment: Thank you. What about the second question?What could  be instead of the $k_i?$